# change conference room booking auto reply language

Tags: email, exchange, outlook, auto-reply

How to change the language that is in this auto reply (yellow color text)? Currently it is in RU and i would like it to be it in EN-US. I haven't found any methods to do this via Exchange management shell... Maybe this needs to be done via command line? Thanks for your answers.

By the way, i have tried the `Set-Mailbox -Identity "LT-ConfRoom-Andromeda@***.com" -Language en-us` command, but that didn't help.

**auto reply screenshot**

[image: link to the auto reply screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, it seems to be based on the time zone of the computer used by the organizer. When the organizer send a meeting request in UTC+2, the auto reply message will show time zone in UTC +2.